# Why can't I paste an image into a PDF Doc in Preview? (need to insert wet signature)

Tags: pdf, preview

If Preview allows entering textboxes and drawing shapes and lines and even coloring them, why is it impossible to paste an image onto the PDF document? Isn't it exactly the same concept? Why does one work but not the other?

Edit: what I want to do is add a wet signature (signed with ink). So I have my ink written signature as a JPEG file of a scan I took of it. But no way to port it into the PDF document directly (work around would be to convert PDF to PNG and back to PDF).

Preview allows for a digital signature. But I'm not looking for digital.

Comment: You should ask **Apple** why they did not include that functionally.  [https://www.apple.com/feedback/](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

Comment: All I was trying to do is add my wet signature as a scanned image on the "sign here" field of a PDF document. But apple wants it to be a pain to do this without paying Adobe.

Comment: Just use the one for **macOS** as it is, by default, a part of it, so to speak. [https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html)

Comment: If you want to add your signature, Preview actually has support for this. Please edit your question to focus on the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @nohillside I need a wet signature. Preview only lets me write down a digital signature. I edited the question.

Comment: What is the difference between a wet and a digital signature?

Comment: It's when you physically sign on a paper with a pen.

Comment: You can physically sign on a piece of paper and then using that signature you can copy it to make the signature.  Is that what you want or don't want?

Comment: @jmh yes that is what i want. I have the wet signature as a jpeg image. But i am unable to copy and paste it into document.

Comment: The method to create a Preview signature has an option to use the computer's camera to create a Preview signate,

Comment: I updated my answer as the scope of the question changed.  Adding a signature is still *an annotation*.  See: https://9to5mac.com/2014/02/15/how-to-use-preview-to-put-signatures-on-pdfs-pages-documents-and-mail-messages/ and not an *edit.*

Comment: Information in the linked 9to5mac.com article is dated from Feb. 15th 2014 and this "Alternatively, if you don’t have a document to sign at the moment, you can open the Tools menu in Preview, then choose Annotate > Signature > “Create Signature from Built-in iSight…”." doesn't represent the right path or steps with more current releases of **macOS**. In **Preview**, if you have no signatures already, you need to go to: **Tools** > **Annotate** > **Signature** > **Manage Signatures...** > **Camera**

Answer (score 8):

**It's not the same concept.  There's *annotating* a PDF and then there's *editing* a PDF.**

Annotating is also known as "marking up" a document.  Inserting an image is editing it.  Preview isn't a PDF editor.

Think of it as a written document submitted to a teacher, professor, or a manager at work.  They may take a red pen and write comments in the margin, make several comments and circle it or box it in, strike out portions, correct spelling, etc.  However, inserting an image would change the whole document.  The reviewer isn't going to rewrite/reformat your document so that the image would fit.

To get another perspective of this, consider the two PDF products from [Adobe](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/pdf-reader.html) are:

- Acrobat Reader (Free)
- Acrobat Pro ($12.99/mo)

Reader allows you to do everything that Preview does from marking up, signing and even filling out and collecting responses from PDF forms.  However, you can't edit the document (which includes inserting graphics).  For that, you need the Pro version (if using Adobe; there are other editors available on the market).

**Signatures**

Preview allows for the capture of signatures via the following methods:

- Sign on your trackpad.
- Capture with your camera
- Capture by using your finger or Apple Pencil with your iPhone or iPad

You’ll find this on the *Markup Toolbar* and then selecting *Sign*.  You can find full details on how to do this on Apple’s support document [Fill out and sign PDF forms in Preview on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/fill-out-and-sign-pdf-forms-prvw35725/mac).

[Acrobat Reader allows you to use a graphic image as your signature](https://helpx.adobe.com/reader/using/sign-pdfs.html).

> To sign a PDF document or form, you can type, draw, or **insert an image of your handwritten signature**. You can also add text, such as your name, company, title, or the date. When you save the document, the signature and text become part of the PDF.

<sup>(Emphasis mine).</sup>

#### Free PDF Editor

As of 18-Oct-2022, [Firefox Browser (v106.0) includes a built in PDF editor](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/106.0/releasenotes/)

Comment: Inserting colored shapes is adding additional pixels to the PDF, thereby editing it. Adding an image to the document is also adding additional pixels to the PDF, thereby editing it. I don't understand how one fundamentally is different from the other. I am not changing the underlying text in either case.

Comment: Its called annotating.  Acrobat Reader allows you to use an image as a “stamp” (like a rubber stamp) but it’s *very* limited.  Preview doesn’t allow you to do this at all.  Inserting an image, as far as the software publishers are concerned, is called *editing*.  I didn’t define  the terminology, they did.

Answer (score 6):

Preview can add signature from camera, so if you still have the original and your Mac has camera, open Markup Toolbar, click Sign button and choose Camera, then put up the original in front of the camera, click Done after Preview successfully capture it.

Otherwise [here is a nifty trick posted in this forum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410104/17238):

> - Open your image file
>   *(in Preview)*
> - Select All (Command-A)
> - Copy (Command-C)
> - Paste (Command-V)
>
> Now you have a copy of your image pasted above your old image. This is
> apparently meaningless, but the new copy is an object.
>
> - Click on the new image (round blue corners appear, no marching ants)
> - Copy (Command-C)
> - Paste on your PDF document. The image is an object, moveable and resizable.

Comment: Wow, insane. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

It IS possible to insert an image into a PDF in Mac OSX Preview. There is extremely non-obvious step required which had me convinced that this was not possible for a long time.

A quick summary is:

- Open 1) the PDF and 2) the image you want to insert in OSX Preview.
- "Select all" in the image then "Copy".
- Then "Paste" the image back into the image file itself! This is the wacky extra step required, it turns the image into an "object" that can now be moved into the PDF file.
- Copy the new object (that you just pasted into the image file)
- Now select the PDF and "paste". Now, resize and position the image as required.

This can from an answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410104/218990 with the critical commenton the hidden step: `I had to read this slowly to realize that there is the extra, non-obvious step of "pasting" the source image into the source image file before you can paste it into the target file. Thank you! – Nat Kuhn`

Comment: Aren't these steps basically the same as those in the previous answer?

Comment: This might be more useful as edits to the original answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a good solution, but here's how I did something similar.  I opened the PDF in GraphicConverter, added the image, and saved again as PDF.

The downside is that the new PDF is saved as all image instead of text and image.