# I cannot rearrange pages of a PDF in Preview

Tags: high-sierra, pdf, preview

Trying to learn how to use my camera, I downloaded [this PDF manual](https://www.cameramanuals.org/bronica/bronica_etrc.pdf). Once I opened it in **Preview**, I noticed that the pages were not in the right order, so I tried moving them in the left-side drawer to reorder them. But **Preview** wouldn't let me.

I usually have no issue reordering pages of a PDF by dragging them around. But for some reason, I cannot rearrange this document (I can't rotate the pages either).

I checked, and the file isn't locked and I have read and write permissions.

**Why can't I reorder the pages of this PDF file?**

Answer (score 4):

The PDF is, somehow, locked against editing.

Here is the workaround I found, to achieve the desired result without having to use a third-party app. The idea is to duplicate the PDF from Preview in a way that will remove the restrictions.

Open the PDF and chose `File` then `Print`. In the dialog, chose size and orientation, then click on `PDF` on the bottom left, then `Print to PDF`.

Open the new file. It can now be modified at will, like any unlocked PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, reordering pages requires copying, which is not allowed for that PDF.

Preview: Tools / Show Inspector / Lock tab gives this:

[image]

This image is from Preview in El Capitan. In High Sierra it says "You may copy from this PDF"!

Comment: Very strange, when I look at the Inspector for this document, I get something [completely different](https://imgur.com/a/n6wrJYW) (on High Sierra).

Comment: I found a workaround by creating a PDF from the Print command, and the created PDF could be reordered.

Comment: @MicroMachine, yes, in the meantime I've tested it on High Sierra and got the same results as you. The mystery remains. Printing to a PDF is the solution I've used in the past.

Comment: @MicroMachine Nice workaound, why don't you expand your comment into an answer? If no other answer provides a better solution, you could then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf file appears to be encrypted.  You can use a tool like qpdf https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf to decrypt the pdf and gain full permissions on the file.

I found a similar question/answer here https://superuser.com/a/924794 and running the following command `qpdf --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf` seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot *edit* a PDF in preview, you can only annotate and  yes, [there is  a distinction between editing. and annotation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391698/119271).

To edit a PDF you will need  a tool like Adobe Acrobat (not the reader) or  any of the many 3rd party utilities designed to  do  so; the good ones  are  generally paid

Additionally, you can  [edit PDFs in  Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-a-pdf-b2d1d729-6b79-499a-bcdb-233379c2f63a) as  well as  LibreOffice, it's not  as  seamless as  Acrobat but if  you own/subscribe to Office you don't have to purchase something else. LibreOffice is  free, of  course ( I prefer Word). Pages may  have this  ability, but I'm  not  a user of  it  so  I cannot confirm.

Comment: Preview allows pages to be rearranged.

Comment: I find that I can open a pdf in preview, delete a page or two and add other new pages...

Comment: You can edit page order and delete pages of a PDF in Preview. Just drag and drop to desired position.