# In Preview, how do I change certain text color to a different color on a PDF?

Tags: pdf, preview, text, color

I'm using Mac Big Sur and I would like to change the certain selected text color on my PDF to a different color.  I like Preview because it is a free application (open to other free applications).  I selected the text in question, clicked on the markup tool and tried picking a different color

[image]

but nothing happened.

What is a way I can change selected text color to a different color in a PDF on Mac?

Comment: That’s [editing the PDF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391698/119271). Preview does annotations but you can’t change content

Comment: I don't think you will find a free PDF editor, but I hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mac Big Sur and seeking a solution to modify the selected text color within a PDF, various options are available to you.

Consider exploring alternative PDF editing applications that provide enhanced text color customization features. Some of my personal favorites include Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and [PDFSimpli](https://pdfsimpli.com/pdf-editor/), which offer comprehensive text customization capabilities. After selecting your preferred application, download it from their respective websites and follow the installation instructions to set it up on your Mac.

Once installed, launch the PDF editing application and open the desired PDF file using the "File" or "Open" function within the software. Locate the text color customization tools, which may be found in the toolbar or menu options. Look for features such as "Text Properties," "Text Formatting," or "Markup Tools" that facilitate changes to the selected text color.
To apply a new color to the selected text, use the appropriate selection tool within the PDF editing application to highlight the desired text. Then, within the text customization tools, locate the color picker or text color settings. Choose your preferred color from the available palette or input the color code to apply it to the selected text.

After making the necessary modifications, save the edited PDF file within the PDF editing application using the "Save" or "Save As" option provided. Remember to consult the user guides or documentation provided by the specific PDF editing application to ensure you make the most of its features.

Answer (score 0):

Preview can *annotate* a PDF, but it cannot *edit* it; changing the color of text is considered editing.

There are ways to edit a PDF, however.

- [Firefox (as of v106) allows you to edit PDFs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391698/119271) directly in the browser window.
- [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/).  You can open the PDF in Draw and edit the PDF.
- [Acrobat](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat.html) Software ($$).  The defacto PDF creator/editor
- Microsoft Word ($$).  Defacto Office application.  PDFs can be edited directly in Word