# Force Quit preview, and now it won't open the same document I was viewing all day

Tags: pdf, preview, force-quit

I was editing this file, and marking it up, highlighting etc, adding picture to it (as described in [Add images to existing PDF with Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378888/add-images-to-existing-pdf-with-preview)), when suddenly `Preview` froze up and would not budge for a min or so. So I forced quit it, and then when I tried to open it again this error message shows up:

> The file “...pdf” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file
> format that Preview doesn’t recognise.

Same message when opening in `Adobe Reader` app (which I downloaded to take a look to see if it's just a `Preview` issue).

Did `Preview` corrupt my file? How can I get it back? It's pretty important for an exam and I don't have another annotated copy!!! Please help :(

Comment: You can try opening your PDF in Safari to check whether it is damaged.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Preview` may have corrupted your file. If you have been 'saving' it continously, there is one thing you can try -

1. Open the file in `Preview`.
2. When you get the error message, click OK to dismiss it.
3. Then cick on **File** > **Revert To** > **Browse All Versions...** on the `Preview` menu bar.

[image: Screenshot - Preview "Revert To"]

4. This *may* show you all the previous versions of your file. Use the slider on the right-hand side to browse the previous versions of your document.
5. Choose one of the previous versions of your document. Then click **Restore** (or hold the Option key, then click **Restore a Copy** to create a duplicate file).

Depending on how corrupt the document is, this may or not work. (More info - [View and restore past versions of documents on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40710/mac)).